# To make a react quiz-builder

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, jsx

Quiz-making apps are a common part of the basic project one takes while learning React. But in these projects, we generally pre-define an array of questions and the options corresponding to each array using code like this:(Code taken from Code Camp)

```
    const questions = [
    {
        questionText: 'What is the capital of France?',
        answerOptions: [
            { answerText: 'New York', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'London', isCorrect: false },
            { answerText: 'Paris', isCorrect: true },
            { answerText: 'Dublin', isCorrect: false },
        ],
    },]
```

However, while trying to make an app such as Google forms using entirely using React, which takes questions and its options from users, I am facing difficulty. The problem I am facing is that I don't know without the use of PHP, how can I take a response to save it in cookies, and then render the same question and its responses back in DOM as a quiz window.
Kindly share the code snippet on how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure about using cookies for this particular case, but why not just use a backend? you can use firebase (or firestore) if your use case fits (mainly just a prototype) or you can develop your backend with node.js with some database (e.g. mongodb if you prefer noSQL, or postgreSQL if you prefer SQL).

you could create, for example in this case, some kind of "room" where the admin/creator of the room could join and then in the same view "collaborates" on creating the question and the answers. using firebase/firestore should be quite easy as it supports realtime out-of-the-box, or if you develop your own backend you need to figure out websockets so changes can be viewed realtime

Comment: Yes, using the back-end is a possible solution but here state inside an ES6 class has to be used for this problem.